# POST data only if you are authenticated user- django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

models.py

```
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    day_of_week = models.IntegerField(choices=((0, 'Sunday'), (1, 'Monday'), (2, 'Tuesday'), (3, 'Wednesday'), (4, 'Thursday'), (5, 'Friday'), (6, 'Saturday')))
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
```

serializer.py

```
class OpeningHoursSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OpeningHours
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ("user",)
```

views.py

```
class OpeningHoursViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OpeningHours.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OpeningHoursSerializer
    authentication_classes = [CustomAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

authentication.py

```
class CustomAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        username = request.META.get('HTTP_USERNAME')
        if not username:
            return None
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such user')
        return (user, None)
```

I want only authenticated user to be able to perform POST method . I have set the key as HTTP_USERNAME and value as username (which I have created in Django admin) on postman header before making a post request but I'm still getting error:

> "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using username you can use jwt authentication and use it as a token in your header and send a post request to your server where it will be handled with the use of permissions class where it verifies the token and handles request.